# How can I get Numpy to give an array of lists instead of tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I make a numpy array out of my data, I get (as expected) a list of lists, but when I declare data types for them, I get what appears to be a list of tuples, which is no good. This is a problem because numpy seems to think that the first array is a 2D array, while the second is a 1D array (it gives its `.shape` as `(9,)`. I'd like to be able to maintain the usability of the 2D array but give it data types as below. Is there a way to do that?

```
>>> np.array(mtest)

array([[',', '7.174707364110744'],
       ['the', '5.260736372733581'],
       ['.', '2.630943297842565'],
       ['of', '2.505952403774265'],
       ['and', '2.309647686709941'],
       ['a', '1.7517895552087845'],
       ['to', '1.7414375486448457'],
       [';', '1.5612359529022042']], 
      dtype='<U18')

>>> np.array(mtest, dtype=[('token', np.unicode_, 64),('perc', np.float)])

array([(',', 7.174707364110744), ('the', 5.260736372733581),
       ('.', 2.630943297842565), ('of', 2.505952403774265),
       ('and', 2.309647686709941), ('a', 1.7517895552087845),
       ('to', 1.7414375486448457), (';', 1.5612359529022042)], 
      dtype=[('token', '<U64'), ('perc', '<f8')])
```

Comment: What you have here is a [`record array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html), and this is how it is displayed. Note that first one isn't list of lists, it's an array of arrays.

Comment: I know them as *structured arrays* (non-trivial dtype), @AshwiniChaudhary. AFAIK record arrays are a subclass of `ndarrays`. Both can have trivial and non-trivial dtypes. The difference for record arrays is the possibility to access fields as members: `arr.field1` is `arr['field1']`

Answer (score 2):

As @Ashwini commented, these are neither lists of lists nor lists of tuples, they're both numpy arrays.  You can still access "columns" (actually called "fields", here) and "rows" (actually called "records") from that new array.  I don't recommend converting it to a list of anything.

```
a = np.array(mtest, dtype=[('token', np.unicode_, 64),('perc', np.float)])

>>> a['token']
array([',', 'the', '.', 'of', 'and', 'a', 'to', ';'],
      dtype='<U64')

>>> a['perc']
array([ 7.17470736,  5.26073637,  2.6309433 ,  2.5059524 ,  2.30964769,
        1.75178956,  1.74143755,  1.56123595])

>>> a[2]
('.', 2.630943297842565)
```

The above is not a tuple:

```
>>> type(a[2])
numpy.void

>>> a[2].dtype
dtype([('token', '<U64'), ('perc', '<f8')])
```

Comment: The problem is, numpy doesn't seem to think the second array (the one that looks like a list of tuples) is a 2D array anymore--it gives its shape as (9,) and functions that need a 2D array can't use this array. But the first array (the one that looks like a list of lists) works just fine. So I need a way to keep the 2D array with the data type labels. I wasn't too clear about that in the question, so I'll update it.

Comment: That's correct, @Jono, it is a 1D array of "records", hence the different terminology of "records" and "fields".  This is necessary because a numpy array is required to have a single `dtype` for _all_ elements, but your array has two dtypes so this is impossible.  You should be clear about why you (or that function) need a 2D array.

Comment: Ah I see. So if I convert the floats here to strings, then I'll be able to work with it as a 2D array. But I think the analytic functions I'm using need the numbers to be ints, so I'll need to figure that out.

Comment: @Jono, yes exactly, or if the function you're using will accept it you can always convert to an actual list-of-lists with `map(list, a)`.

Answer (score 0):

While the second array isn't a list of tuples (any more than the 1st is a list of lists), its expression in pure Python is.  It's not a problem with your `dtype`.  It's just how `numpy` programmers have chosen to construct this interface.

To create the 1st 2d array I can start with a list of lists:

```
 x1 = array([[',', '7.174707364110744'],
       ['the', '5.260736372733581'],
       ...
       [';', '1.5612359529022042']], 
      dtype='<U18')
```

to create the 2nd, with fields, I have to convert it to a list of tuples:

```
list_of_tuples=[(r[0],float(r[1])) for r in x1]
x2=np.array(list_of_tuples,dtype=[('token', np.unicode_, 64),('perc', np.float)])
x2.tolist()
```

producing:

```
[(u',', 7.174707364110744),
 ...
 (u'to', 1.7414375486448457),
 (u';', 1.5612359529022042)]
```

Trying to use a list of lists produces an `'expected a readable buffer object'` error.

An element of `x2` is a numpy array, shape `()`.  Whereas a row of `x1` has shape `(2,)`.  `x2[2]` not only displays as a tuple, it can only be assigned a tuple:

```
x2[2]=(',',1.3)
```

But it isn't immutable (like a true tuple)

```
x2[2][0] = ';'
x2[2]['token']
```

If it was a real tuple this assignment would produce an error as in:

```
x2[2].tolist()[0]=':' # TypeError
```

If you need a list of lists expression of your 2nd array, use

```
[list(r) for r in x2.tolist()]
```